# Hiding div elements in mobile view of webpage

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a MEAN stack application. Currently, I am trying to hide certain div elements in mobile view using css media rules. And in mobile view listing it using a button dropdown which sets collapsed to true/false on click using ng-click. Its working as expected. But in mobile view, if the dropdown is activated and I expand browser to larger size, the menu comes in the web view which is not expected. Can anyone help on the same?

Below is part of the code:

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#sidbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidbar" ng-init="sidCollapsed=true" ng-click="sidCollapsed=!sidCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>



<div id="sidbar" collapse="sidCollapsed" class="sidbar">
            <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/home'}" href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/profile'}" ng-show="user" href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/admin'}" ng-show="user && user.roles.indexOf('admin')>=0" href="#/admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/forms'}" ng-show="user" href="#/forms">Forms</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



css:

@media (min-width: 768px){
.sidbar {
    display:none;
}}
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap ? if so, you can use the `.hidden-sm` `.visible-xs-*` class: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: It doesnt work out. Please check the image I uploaded in the answer reply below

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things, you're using Bootstrap so you can use the `hidden-xs` class

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidbar" ng-init="sidCollapsed=true" ng-click="sidCollapsed=!sidCollapsed">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>



<div id="sidbar" collapse="sidCollapsed" class="sidbar hidden-xs">
  <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">-->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/home'}" href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/profile'}" ng-show="user" href="#/profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/admin'}" ng-show="user && user.roles.indexOf('admin')>=0" href="#/admin">Admin</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ng-class="{'active':$location.path() == '/forms'}" ng-show="user" href="#/forms">Forms</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can find out more usable classes for showing and hiding elements dependent on browser size in the Bootstrap documentation.

- [Responsive Utility Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Comment: I have tried using hidden-sm and hidden-xs...it doesnt work out. Initially in the large view it is hidden as expected. But when i do the below it goes for a toss: Switch to mobile view. Expand the collapsible view. Switch back to larger view.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZUl.png
          [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1jl3.png
          [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WMJsC.png
          [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNVv.png

Comment: Are you sure you dont have 2 sets of buttons in your HTML?

Comment: In the mobile view, the sidebar menu and header menu are displayed as two collapsible buttons. So yes i have two buttons in the mobile view

Comment: I guess the last image was misleading...please check this...http://imgur.com/pyMOfxt

Comment: @VikasJ I dont fully understand you're problem. Could you make a full example to show what its currently doing as I can't figure out exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Suppose there is menu links as header(username,logout) and sidebar(home,profile etc). In mobile view i am trying to hide the header and sidebar into two buttons which expands to dropdown on click using toggling of variable to true or false on ng-click. Heres the web view and mobile view initially which works as expected. http://imgur.com/cXhIx88   and http://imgur.com/17sOJEg

Comment: But when i now expand from the current mobile view and return to web view(with collapsed state button), the sidebar menu gets duplicated as : http://imgur.com/BCF2HTQ   and http://imgur.com/qCuLnRb ... i hope u understood now

Comment: Got it fixed using hidden-lg to hide the duplicate links when in large window view